# a / the occasional game

Tags: definite-article, singular-vs-plural

I'd like to know which of the following is natural English:

> 1. Although Jimmy prefers to read in his leisure time, he does play **occasional** baseball **games** with us.
> 2. Although Jimmy prefers to read in his leisure time, he does play **an occasional** baseball **game** with us.
> 3. Although Jimmy prefers to read in his leisure time, he does play **the occasional** baseball **game** with us.

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4):

All three are natural and acceptable English. You could also say "he does play baseball games with us occasionally".